# Convert String with month name to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using `pickadate.js` which returns the date in this format:

```
8 March, 2017
```

I would like to convert this to the `datetime` format of:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: You can configure pickadate.js to format the date otherwise, e.g. `$('.datepicker').pickadate({formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Python, this is an easy exercise in using the `datetime` format strings:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "8 March, 2017"
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d %B, %Y')
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) table for a full description of all the format qualifiers.

Here I use the `datetime.strptime` method to convert your datepicker.js string to a Python datetime object.  And I use the `.strftime` method to print that object out as a string using the format you desire.  At first those format strings are going to be hard to remember, but you can always look them up. And they well organized, in the end.

I do wonder, though: might it be better to stay in JavaScript than switch over to Python for this last step?  Of course, if you are using Python elsewhere in your process, this is an easy solution.

Comment: Format specifiers `A`/`a` and `B`/`b` are weekday and month, respectively, because they usually come in that order when both are specified. In both cases, the lowercase letter refers to the abbreviation, the uppercase to the full name.

Comment: My controller is in Python so I prefer a solution in Python over JavaScript. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: and by extension: `s = "8-Mar-2017, 23:42:42.314"` → `d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d-%b-%Y, %H:%M:%S.%f')`

Answer (score 11):

Mark Reed's advice might be best in your case. One frequently overlooked alternative for dates is the **arrow** module, which offers some interesting features. In this case you can do:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.get('8 March, 2017', 'D MMMM, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
'2017-03-08'
```

As an example of a feature, if you capture that date you could format it in Russian.

```
>>> aDate = arrow.get('8 March, 2017', 'D MMMM, YYYY')
>>> aDate.format('YYYY MMMM DD', locale='ru')
'2017 марта 08'
```