# how to convert '22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30) ' "22 7 2020 " in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date-format

I want to convert `22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30)`  to `22 7 2020` in order
to insert it into my database.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [strftime() and strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

`strptime` is used to change your date string into a `datetime` format. `strftime` then turns it back into another formatted string, presuming that is what you wish to do.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30)'

dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M (%Z 4.30)')

out = dt.strftime('%d %m %Y')

print(out)
```

Returns

```
22 07 2020
```

One problem is that `strptime` will struggle with the way the offset (GMT 4.30) is formatted at the end. Since the term 'GMT' is all you should need to retrieve the timezone, I suggest stripping the rest out using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) - if the timezone matters to you.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

s = '22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30)'

s_stripped = re.sub('\(([A-Z]+).+\)', r'\1', s)
# s_stripped is '22-Jul-2020 14:00 GMT'

dt = datetime.strptime(s_stripped, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M %Z')

out = dt.strftime('%d %m %Y')

print(out)
```

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980662/convert-string-with-month-name-to-datetime/42980752) can help with converting month name to number and then use `strftime()` and `strptime()` methods to format your datetime object to appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only the date part from the string, you can use this:

```
from datetime import datetime


s = "22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30)"
d = datetime.strptime(s.split()[0], "%d-%b-%Y")
desired_output = '{d.day} {d.month} {d.year}'.format(d=d)
print(desired_output)
x = datetime.strftime(d, "%d %m %Y")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
22 7 2020
22 07 2020
```

After creating the `datetime` object from the string, I have shown both string formatting and `strftime` to convert the `datetime` to required format. As you can see the `strftime` returns a zero padded month which is not required for your case.

Reference:

- [strftime and strptime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
- [Stackoverflow answer to convert datetime to a formatted string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384639/3129414)

Answer (score -3):

You can use Regex to accomplish, but I would like to use in this case `replace()` method, it will replace the something to something like below:

```
date = "22-Jul-2020 14:00"
newDate = date.replace("-", " ")[:11]
print(newDate)
```

Output:

```
22 Jul 2020
```

learn more about [Replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_replace.htm)

Happy Codin`!

Comment: You shouldn't use ';' in the end of python lines. Also, the output you have is not the actual output of your code

Comment: thank you for the answer but it is not what I want. I want "22-Jul-2020 14:00 (GMT 4.30)" should be changed to its equivalent "22 7 2020". no extra info and time.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi, my apology, I correct the answer, please have a look! I appreciate you for correction

Comment: @GeorgeBou I like to use the semicolon ( for terminating the line ). it not essential to not use either!