# Date formatting (e.g. Jan 02, 2020) using Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am sorry to ask this silly question but I am stuck in converting date format (Jan 02, 2020) to another date format ('%Y-%m-%d'). Would anyone be able to give me a hand here? Thank you very much.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: you can find solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980662/convert-string-with-month-name-to-datetime/42980752

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String with month name to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980662/convert-string-with-month-name-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is a two-step process:

- Convert the input into an internal representation, which in this case will almost certainly be either `date` or `datetime`. For simple cases where you know the format, the conversion can be done with the [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method.
- Convert the internal representation into the required output form. In this case, that will be either [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) or [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), depending on which internal representation you use; they both pretty much work the same way.

Comment: I should note that this structure is applicable to a lot of problems in programming; many programs/functions have basically the same three-step structure: (1) deal with the input; (2) apply the needed transformation or calculation (in this case none); (3) prepare the output.

Comment: Thnak you sabik and puffin. This is helpful. I am working on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
temp = datetime.datetime.strptime('Jan 02, 2020', '%b %d, %Y')
result = temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format = '%b %d, %Y')

Hi, but after I ran the above code, an error occurred. (valueError: time data 'Aug 19,2020' does not match format '%b %d, %Y' (match)). Would you mind to tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Formats are extremely precise.  I think you forgot.a space after the comma.

Comment: I left a space here already.

format = '%b %d, %Y'

Comment: But the date 'Aug 19,2020' doesn't have a space after the comma...

Comment: Then delete the space after the comma from the format.